# Add click event to highcharts Sunburst level that adds style to any class

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, highcharts

I have this issue where i would like to toggle the style `display: none;` to a class in my dataLabelFormatter `.chart-amount-visibility`. It should only happen whenever a level has been expanded.I just cant seem to wrap my head around how to do it.

Here's how my SunBurst chart looks like

[image: SunBurst chart]

And here when it's expanded

[image: SunBurst chart expanded]

You see the amount, that should not be visible in the inner pie whenever it's not expanded. That should only be visible whenever any section is expanded.

Here's my current code:

```
async generateSunburstData(strContainerID: string, strCurrencyCode: string, oSunburstData: SunburstData) {
        const arrOrderTypeColors: { [key: string]: string } = {
            Pre: '#8BBC21',
            Stock: '#528F8F'
        };

        oSunburstData.arrData.forEach(dataItem => {
            if (dataItem.name === 'Pre' || dataItem.name === 'Stock') {
                dataItem.color = arrOrderTypeColors[dataItem.name];
            }
        });

        const fTotalSum = oSunburstData.arrData.reduce((fTotalSum, DataPoint) => fTotalSum + DataPoint.value, 0);
        if (fTotalSum <= 0) {

            const strTurnoverContainer = document.getElementById('turnoverPieChart');
            const strMarginContainer = document.getElementById('marginPieChart');

            if (strTurnoverContainer) {
                strTurnoverContainer.innerHTML = '<div class="no-data-available-text"><p class="no-data-available-header">Turnover share on sales channels</p><p class="no-data-available-unset">No data available to display the chart.</p></div>';
            }

            if (strMarginContainer) {
                strMarginContainer.innerHTML = '<div class="no-data-available-text"><p class="no-data-available-header">Margin share on sales channels</p><p class="no-data-available-unset">No data available to display the chart.</p></div>';
            }
            
            return;
        }

        interface DataPoint {
            parent?: string;
            value: number;
            level: number;
            name: string;
            id: string;
        }

        const dataLabelFormatter = function () {
            const oPoint: DataPoint = this.point;
            const oSeries = this.series;

            const iLevel = oPoint.parent ? 1 : 2;

            if (iLevel === 2) {
                const parentTotal = oSeries.data.reduce((fTotalSum: number, dataPoint: DataPoint) => {
                    return dataPoint.parent === oPoint.parent ? fTotalSum + dataPoint.value : fTotalSum;
                }, 0);

                const strPercentage = (oPoint.value / parentTotal) * 100;
                const strFormattedPercentage = strPercentage.toFixed(2) + '%';

                return `<div class="inner-pie-chart"><b style="font-size: 14px;">${oPoint.name}</b><br><span dy="15" style="font-size: 12px;">${strFormattedPercentage}</span><br><span class="chart-amount-visibility" dy="28" style="font-size: 12px;">${number_format(oPoint.value, 0)} ${strCurrencyCode}</span></div>`;
            } else {
                return oPoint.name;
            }
        };


        const fnFormatter = function () {
            const oPoint = this.point,
                oSeries = this.series;
            let chartTotal;

            if (oPoint.level === 1) {
                chartTotal = oSeries.__myTotal || (oSeries.__myTotal = oSeries.data.reduce((a: number, b: DataPoint) => a + b.value, 0));
            } else {
                const siblings = oSeries.data.filter((p: DataPoint) => p.parent === oPoint.parent);
                chartTotal = siblings.reduce((a: number, b: DataPoint) => a + b.value, 0);
            }

            const fPercentage = oPoint.value / chartTotal;
            let strPercentage = fPercentage === undefined ? 'N/A' : number_format(fPercentage * 100, 2);

            return `<b>${this.point.name}</b><br>Percentage: ${strPercentage} % <br> Amount: ${number_format(this.point.value, 0)} ${strCurrencyCode}`;
        }

        return Sunburst.Highcharts.chart(document.getElementById(strContainerID)!, <Highcharts.Options>{
            chart: {
                backgroundColor: '#FCFCFC',
                height: 436,
            },
            navigation: {
                buttonOptions: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: oSunburstData.strTitle,
                style: {
                    color: '#3F3F3F'
                }
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Percentage reflects the size of the pie cutout',
                style: {
                    color: '#3F3F3F'
                },
            },
            plotOptions: {
                sunburst: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    animation: false,
                    dataLabels: {
                        color: '#FFFFFF',
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: dataLabelFormatter,
                    }
                },
            },
            series: [<Highcharts.SeriesSunburstOptions>{
                custom: {
                    percentage: 'parent'
                },
                breadcrumbs: {
                    buttonTheme: {
                        padding: 8,
                        stroke: '#CCCCCC',
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        style: {
                            color: '#333333',
                            fill: '#333333',
                        }
                    },
                    floating: true,
                    position: {
                        align: 'left'
                    },
                    showFullPath: false,
                    formatter: function () {
                        const customText = '< Go back';

                        return `${customText} `;
                    },
                },
                type: 'sunburst',
                data: oSunburstData.arrData,
                allowTraversingTree: true,
                borderRadius: 8,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                levels: [{
                    level: 1,
                    levelIsConstant: false,
                    levelSize: {
                        unit: 'weight',
                        value: 3,
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        filter: {
                            property: 'outerArcLength',
                            operator: '>',
                            value: 64
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    level: 2,
                    colorByPoint: true,
                }]
            }],
            tooltip: {
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: fnFormatter
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you send a link to a working online demo with sample data?